# Select row with shortest string in one column if there are duplicates in another column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a database with rows like this

```
ID  PNR     NAME
1   35      Television
2   35      Television, flat screen
3   35      Television, CRT
4   87      Hat
5   99      Cup
6   99      Cup, small
```

I want to select each individual type of item (television, hat, cup) - but for the ones that have multiple entries in PNR I only want to select the one with the shortest NAME. So the result set would be

```
ID  PNR     NAME
1   35      Television
4   87      Hat
5   99      Cup
```

How would I construct such a query using SQLite? Is it even possible, or do I need to do this filtering in the application code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQLite 3.7.11, you can [use MIN() or MAX() to select a row in a group](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg):

```
SELECT ID,
       PNR,
       Name,
       min(length(Name))
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY PNR;
```

Comment: Is `select ID, PNR, Name .... group by PNR` actually supported, or in other words: which of the rows of a group with common `PNR` will be selected as the single row for this `PNR` in  the result? Will it also work if the row with `ID=1` contained `Television, flat`, and the row with `ID=2` contained `Television`?

Comment: @StephanLechner See the link.

Comment: That's really handy. A picky side note would be that "There is still an ambiguity if two or more of the input rows have the same minimum or maximum value", but thats really picky now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN(length(name))`-aggregate function to find out the minimum length of several names; the slightly tricky thing is to get corresponding `ID` and `NAME` into the result. The following query should work:

```
select mt1.ID, mt1.PNR, mt1.Name
from MyTable mt1 inner join (
  select pnr, min(length(Name)) as minlength
  from MyTable group by pnr) mt2
  on mt1.pnr = mt2.pnr and length(mt1.Name) = mt2.minlength
```